# How to fix "is in unnamed module of loader 'app';" with hibernate.load

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I'm getting the following error after i try to load an entity by id in hibernate

```
Course is in unnamed module of loader 'app';
```

here is an example of my hibernate load code:

```
 Course temp = (Course) currentSession.load(Course.class, cid);
```

P.S: i have thymeleaf and java 11 if that matters

Important : I am using spring-boot-devtools 
If i remove devtools from maven everything works fine

Comment: I can't help you as to what the issue is, but I would like to thank you for pointing out that that issue gets caused by spring-boot-devtools -- saved me so much time by just removing that from my project!

Answer (score 4):

I have got same issue, and find answer here - https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/386. If "Course" class nested in external .jar, you shold include this .jar to load by “restart” devtools classloader. How to do it describe here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @vasilii_yar I am sorry I can't understand the solutions in that link, can you please explain the answer?

Comment: @Sanal S Hi! If you get issue - <ClassName> is in unnamed module of loader 'app', you have two variants: 1. Delete spring-boot-devtools from maven dependencies 2. Create file spring-devtools.properties in META-INF folder on project class path, and add string  with restart.include.projectcommon=<path to .jar where problem class nested>. If you chose first variant, you lose fast restart option.